# My files are downloading with the wrong names. Please help me fix my PHP

Tags: php, mysql, download

So I have a script to download a video file, and for some reason it is not working. The id, firstname, and lastname variables are from another PHP script that takes values out of a database and opens this downloading script with the variables in the url.

Ok, so the problem. So far everything is working, but when the files are downloaded, they are all called -audio.wav and -video.webm. Please help because I have been having huge trouble on this and this would solve a big problem.

The downloading script:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

$fileNameVideo = $firstname.$lastname."-video.webm";

$filePathVideo = 'videos/' . $fileNameVideo;

if (!file_exists($filePathVideo)) {
    echo "<h1>Error Downloading ".$fileNameVideo."     ".$php_errormsg."</h1><br>";
    return;
}

header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $fileNameVideo);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile($filePathVideo);

echo "<h1>".$fileNameVideo." Downloaded</h1><br>";

?>
```

The script to open the downloading page:

```
<?php
include 'upload/connection.php';
$conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$conn) {
    die("CONNECTION ERROR:  " . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $conn);
if(!$db_selected) {
    die( DB_NAME .' is not available. ERROR: '. mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, fullname, grade, email, sendemail, send, invid, firstname, lastname FROM info WHERE invid = 1 ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row{'id'};
    $firstname = $row{'firstname'};
    $lastname = $row{'lastname'};

    echo "<script>window.open('download-video.php?id=".$id."&firstname=".$firstname."&lastname=".$lastname."', '_blank');window.open('download-audio.php?id=".$id."&firstname=".$firstname."&lastname=".$lastname."', '_blank');</script>";
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$firstname` and  `$lastname` are not set in the download script they should be

```
$_GET['firstname']
```

and

```
$_GET['lastname']
```

as they are part of the url you use the super global array $_GET. not $_POST

Comment: For some reason my code copied wrong. I am updating it.

Comment: @lucadem1313 again GET not POST

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure. Did you echo the variables after retrieving from database. Because I feel  this one needs to change

```
       $id = $row{'id'};
       $firstname = $row{'firstname'};
       $lastname = $row{'lastname'};
```

Into

```
       $id = $row['id'];
       $firstname = $row['firstname'];
       $lastname = $row['lastname'];
```

Please explain the bug or did you try echo the variables after retrieving  from database.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to pick an answer. The problem was that I used $_POST instead of $_GET.